# Check whether a string contains only special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

Is it possible to check whether a string contains only special characters using javascript?

Comment: Yes. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: A field? Not a string?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: *Yes.* If you want a more concrete answer, at least tell us the context and technology.

Comment: Good. Please show us the code you use to access the field, and tell us what exactly you mean by "special character".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match where the string has only characters, that are not in the class defined here as `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`.

```
var regex = /^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Test it...

```
console.log( "My string to test".match(regex) )
console.log( "My string, to test!".match(regex) )
```

Comment: That's not "*only* special characters"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Try below, it should work.

```
function hasOnlySpecialCharater(val) {
    var pattern = /^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    return (pattern.test(val));
}

console.log(hasOnlySpecialCharater("@#$"));
console.log(hasOnlySpecialCharater("ChiragP&^"));
```

Answer (score -1):

We can write this :

```
    function checkOnlySplChar(str) {
            // to check if string contains only special characters 
            var alphaNumOnly = RegExp('/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/');
            return (alphaNumOnly.test(str));
        }
```